# Interpreting interaction coefficients from categorical predictors in lmer

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, interaction

I have 4 mixed effect models that I want to compare - each one has exactly the same structure but a different outcome variable (see summary plot below). I need a statitical test of whether the effects are different from one another.

[image]

I have rejigged the dataframe using pivotlonger, so that the dependent variable, prosociality, (all standardised, numeric) is in one column and the predictors (preferences) are a factor variable in another column. Like this,

```
df.pref %>% select(prosociality, preference)
# A tibble: 262,360 x 2
   prosociality preference
          <dbl> <fct>     
 1       0.594  posrecip  
 2      -0.367  negrecip  
 3      -0.140  altruism  
 4       1.68   trust     
 5       0.662  posrecip  
 6      -0.0709 negrecip  
 7      -0.140  altruism  
 8       1.32   trust     
 9       0.960  posrecip  
10      NA      negrecip  
# ... with 262,350 more rows
```

I've then run a model (with exactly the same fixed and random effects structure as the main models), with a prosociality * preference interaction using lmerTest:

```
m_test <- lmer(prosociality ~ gender + age + physical_wellbeing + subj_math_skills + 
INC_001.logc*preference + (1 | country) +
           (0 + financial_wellbeing | country) +
           (0 + physical_wellbeing | country) +
           (0 + subj_math_skills | country) +
           (0 + INC_001.logc | country),
           data = df.pref, control = lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
```

What I am expecting is that I will get interaction coefficients (using the default treatment contrast) versus the base factor (altruism in the default case as it is first alphabetically) which represent the difference in the SLOPE of each effect versus the base slope. So, for example the wealth:trust interaction should be negative compared to the wealth:altruism (base) interaction.

However the model doesn't show this..

```
summary(m_test)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: prosociality ~ gender + age + physical_wellbeing + subj_math_skills +  
    INC_001.logc * preference + (1 | country) + (0 + physical_wellbeing |  
    country) + (0 + subj_math_skills | country) + (0 + age |      country) + (0 + INC_001.logc | country)
   Data: df.pref
Control: lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 2e+05))


Fixed effects:
                                 Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                     -9.20e-03   2.41e-02  7.62e+01   -0.38  0.70327    
gender1                         -1.16e-02   1.98e-03  2.49e+05   -5.87  4.3e-09 ***
age                             -8.15e-03   4.77e-03  7.44e+01   -1.71  0.09208 .  
physical_wellbeing               1.51e-02   3.76e-03  6.92e+01    4.02  0.00014 ***
subj_math_skills                 1.22e-01   6.55e-03  7.23e+01   18.59  < 2e-16 ***
INC_001.logc                     9.97e-03   7.20e-03  1.20e+02    1.38  0.16889    
preferencetrust                  1.58e-03   5.46e-03  2.50e+05    0.29  0.77176    
preferencenegrecip               4.41e-03   5.46e-03  2.50e+05    0.81  0.41932    
preferenceposrecip               1.42e-03   5.44e-03  2.50e+05    0.26  0.79366    
INC_001.logc:preferencetrust     5.60e-02   5.58e-03  2.50e+05   10.03  < 2e-16 ***
INC_001.logc:preferencenegrecip  7.68e-02   5.59e-03  2.50e+05   13.76  < 2e-16 ***
INC_001.logc:preferenceposrecip  6.41e-02   5.57e-03  2.50e+05   11.51  < 2e-16 ***
```

My interpretation of this output is that the main effect of income and altruism (INC_001.logc = 9.97e-03) is small and non-significant, which it isn't in the main models. And also that the interaction effect of trust (INC_001.logc:preferencetrust = 5.60e-02), for example, is positive which means that the slope of wealth-trust should be GREATER than the slope of wealth-altruism, which is isn't.

I've tried lots of things (checked the dataframe, variables, tried changing contrast coding, looked at emtrends, used different functions e.g. afex::mixed) and I cannot fathom what's going on. I've used this technique before on other data and it has worked fine with the interaction effect coefficients corresponding to differences in slopes. What am I missing?

Comment: Your y-axis on the plot is labeled "preference", not "prosociality" - is this a typo, or is it the wrong plot?

Comment: Hi David - it's the right plot, but the title is misleading taken out of context, the y-axis is "prosociality" - I've changed it now, thanks for pointing this out

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, but what I would do is build a much simpler model to check single effects (no random effects, no covariates, a single interaction, 2 preferences at a time) just to confirm what you're seeing in the plot (which I assume are values that have not been residualized?) is there. Then build the model back up and see when things start to change.

Comment: Hi yes thanks for your comment. I have done that and the point it changes is when I add the interaction effect. I can get exactly the expected model outputs by starting as you say with the simplest model, but as soon as I add the * preference interaction term it starts producing outputs that I can't reconcile